# How can I fix my chewed up LEGO head?

Tags: minifigures, repair

When I was about 8 I used to bite down on loose LEGO heads to "fix" them. Of course after the heads "treatment" they would have chew marks around the neck.

Is there any way to make these marks less noticeable? One of my old favorite LEGO heads have these marks. I can't buy a replacement because the head isn't made anymore.

I could buy one on ebay... If I had my own credit card/paypal/etc. and my mom would gain the knowledge that ebay isn't evil just because it's online. What should I do?

The only idea I have is to put some nail varnish over the chew marks.

[image: here is a photo of the head. You can't really see the chew marks because my webcam sucks and my good camera is dead, but if you look closely you can kind of see how the bottom part of the head is kind of wavy instead of a perfect circle.]

Here's a picture of the head. I don't know if it helps much since you can't really see the chew marks.

Comment: If [this](https://www.bricklink.com/PL/3626bp02.jpg?0) is the minifig head in question, then as TheBrickBlogger says, ordering from Bricklink would be best, it's [available for pennies](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=3626bp02&colorID=3).

Comment: Yeah that's the right head, like I said below though I can't order from their since I'm pretty sure it's illegal due to age restrictions. But thanks for the answer. Atleast I know the part number now.

Comment: Are you able to ask a parent or guardian to help you?

Comment: Probably not. My parents hate buying online and would definitely not buy a replacement head (I can already hear my mom saying "Oh, it's just a small scratch!"). Besides, I have kind of come to accept that there isn't much I can do.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet would still be BrickLink. Many sellers there accept cash, checks or money orders, so you don't necessarily need paypal or a credit card. However if you would like to work on fixing the bite-marks on the head you pictured above, there are several things you can do:

1. If the bite-marks are not too deep, you can sand down the area with very fine sand-paper to make it more even. The sand-paper must be very fine, otherwise the surface would end up getting even, but rough. I have found wet and dry sand-papers the best as it can provide a very smooth finish.
2. You could try your nail-varnish idea, but please note that nail-varnish actually melts the plastic, so use only very little. You might also try other type of clear varnish that is fairly thick. Make sure you try it first on a piece you don't care for to see how it reacts with the plastic.
3. Because plastic is fairly soft, I found that sometimes you can smooth out bite-marks just by the back of a kitchen knife. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wish I could do BrickLink, but I have no bank account or anything (I'm 13). I think I might try the sanding down idea on the neck if desperate, or maybe on the bottom of the head so it fits down the tube thing on the torso all the way. I did the nail varnish thing though. I think it kind of helped but you can still see the chew marks a bit. I put some on the inside so atleast the head is the right tightness now (it got loose after the "surgery" again since it was the only girl head I had back then).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how deep the bite-marks are. For a thin mark, TheBrickBlogger's answer with the sandpaper of kitchen knife should do the trick. For something deeper, heat up a tool of some sort, something with a non-conductive handle, and melt it a little into itself.

Answer (score -1):

You could try filing it with a nailfile or sandpaper.